# How to validate a name by time wise in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation

In my project, there may be multiple shifts called day. Now I want to validate this time so that in the meantime there was no conflicting of time. Or in the simple word, there cannot be the two shift at the same time or between those time.

I tried like following but this do not work:

```php
$shifts = Shift::where('name',$request->name)
            ->whereTime('in_time','>=', $request->in_time)
            ->WhereTime('out_time','<=', $request->out_time)
            ->pluck('name');
            'name' => [
            'required',
            Rule::unique('shifts','name')->where(function ($query) use ($shifts){
                return $query->whereIn('name', $shifts);
            })
        ],
```

Comment: Why don't you create Custom Validation Rules https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#custom-validation-rules

Comment: What is issue you  are facing?

Comment: if i have two shifts in day like one is on 9 am to 7pm and another is on 12pm to 8pm then it will not showing any error, i want to fix this. It should give me error

Answer (score 2):

The query to find overlapping times should be fixed:

```
Shift::where( function ($query) use ($request) {
    # New shift `in_time` is included in another shift
    # i.e. Another shift has not finished yet when this one beings
    $query->where('in_time', '<', $request->in_time )
          ->where('out_time', '>', $request->in_time );

})
->orWhere( function ($query) use ($request) {
    # New shift `out_time` is included in another shift
    # i.e. Another shift starts before this one begins
    $query->where('in_time', '<', $request->out_time )
          ->where('out_time', '>', $request->out_time );
});
```

To put it all together:

```
# Make sure the input is in the right format before using it in a query:

$rules = [
   'in_time' => 'required|date_format:H:i',
   'out_time' => 'required|date_format:H:i',
   'name' => 'required|string|max:100'
];
$request->validate($rules);

# Now check that times aren't overlapping. Just check if a clashing entry exists in the database:

$clash = Shift::where('name', $request->name)
        ->where( function ($query) use ($request) {
            $query->where( function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('in_time', '<', $request->in_time )
                      ->where('out_time', '>', $request->in_time );

            })->orWhere( function ($query) use ($request) {
                $query->where('in_time', '<', $request->out_time )
                      ->where('out_time', '>', $request->out_time );
            });
        })->exists();

# If a clash exists, throw a validation error

if ( $clash ) {
    throw ValidationException::withMessages([
        'name' => "There's an overlapping shift with that name"
    ]);
}
```

It's longer, but safer, and clearly shows what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: thats working nice from previous answer but it still has some issue like below   Name In Time Out Time Status 
Day       08:00 AM  08:00 PM

Comment: The Laravel validation works best for validating values for a single field. Is this logic directly in your controller or in a `FormRequest` class? And what version of Laravel are you on?

Comment: I'd switch around the logic. First validate the values for `in_time`, `out_time` and `name` before using them in a query to your database. For example, if some values are null then your request might fail due to a bad query rather than show a validation error. Then using the validated data, check that the times don't overlap.